# What is the iupac name for ch3ch2cooag?

Tags: nomenclature

Like ch3coo is acetate group and is named accordingly,how to name this one.

Comment: Like acetic then is propionic. IUPAC name as in answer @Oscar Lanzi. By the way simply typing ch3ch2cooh in Google you get it as first or second result depending on language setting. https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/propionic_acid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the acid $\ce{CH_3CH_2COOH}$.  This is clearly the one and only simple carboxylic acid derived from an unsubstituted propane chain, so it's

"Propan-" from the propane chain

plus "-oic acid" from the carboxyl group (we don't need a locant because there is only one place to fit that group)

= propanoic acid

Then the silver salt is silver propanoate, the "-ic acid" part becomes "-ate" just like inorganic salts.